# Identifying Workspaces

Tags: workspaces

New Ubuntu 12.04 User -

Having Workspaces is quite useful, but is there a way to easily identify which is which? In other words, if I have a terminal open in three of the workspaces it would be nice to have (for instance) the background colour of each workspace unique.

Is there any way to do that or something similar (e.g. different wallpaper?)

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You can install [Workspaces Indicator](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/workspaces-indicator-for-ubuntu.html) to help to identifying which workspace you are in.

To do this, first add this to your PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:geod/ppa-geod
```

Then update and install:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-workspaces
```